# Error in the paths of one of the plugins when changing the plugin directory

Tags: directory, paths

I decided to change the standard path to the plugins folder. Now all my plugins are located in site.com/modules

In wp-config I have the following written:

```
define( 'WP_PLUGIN_DIR', dirname(__FILE__) . '/modules' );
define( 'WP_PLUGIN_URL', 'https://example.com/modules' );
define( 'PLUGINDIR', dirname(__FILE__) . '/modules' );
```

In the end, everything works, but plugin JetEngine in the console gives 404 errors on cx-vue-ui.js and vue.min.js.

The fact is that the new path to the folder with plugins is duplicated for some reason and looks like this:

```
//example.com/var/www/data/www/example.com/modules/jet-engine/framework/vue-ui/assets/js/cx-vue-ui.js
//example.com/var/www/data/www/example.com/modules/jet-engine/framework/vue-ui/assets/js/vue.min.js
```

I was looking for a solution to the problem and thought that something was wrong with my settings, but what is strange, everything works in the admin panel, except jetengine.

Did I do everything right? An error in the plugin or did I do something wrong?

Comment: Not sure but seems like `PLUGINDIR` should be relative to `ABSPATH` e.g `define( 'PLUGINDIR', 'modules' );`. Don't think this is the problem though.

Comment: Thanks. I tried it, there are no changes(

Comment: Can you dump the contents of the `WP_PLUGIN_DIR`, `WP_PLUGIN_URL` and `PLUGINDIR` and update your question with the data.

Comment: Sorry, my English is bad. What data do I need to provide? I have in config.php so it is written as in the example above.

Comment: the real contents of your defines show what the contain `echo WP_PLUGIN_DIR` and so on.

Comment: If only one plug-in is showing an issue then that plug-in is probably written incorrectly. You will need to speak to its author.